# How to give access to certain documents in sub folders

Tags: 2010

Hi similar to the last question but here need to provide access (read) to just certain documents under certain folders - can I achieve this using one of the options below?

I have inherited this structure so cannot get rid of the folders at this point

SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 2):

You can set item level permissions in SharePoint 2010. This [LINK](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Manage-permissions-for-a-list-library-folder-document-or-list-item-9d13e7df-a770-4646-91ab-e3c117fcef45#bm4) describes how to do that in SP 2007, but the process is basically the same in 2010:

1. Select the item;
2. Click on Documents tab;
3. Document Permissions button;
4. Break role inheritance for that item;
5. Add/Remove users as needed.

Comment: Hi thanks for this, the document is about four level down from the home page for the particular site. I did what you suggested (I think) and when I looked at site permission I could see the user I had allocated 'view' permission on just the document (and unchecked inherit from parent) but when the users I had provided the access to tried to click onto the icon for the home page (I had hoped they would the get access to the document) they got the  Error: Access Denied box - any suggestions on what I have missed?